# Is there a template for academic paper changes report?

Tags: publications, conference, review-articles

After updating the academic paper as per reviewers comments, one needs to submit the updated paper in parallel to a report of what did he change or why didn't he change. Is there any template for such report? if not, what sections should it contain?

Comment: There is probably no general template, given that some of these accompanying reports/letters are severely restricted (e.g. to have only 100 words), while others can be much more elaborate.

Comment: Some people just use the referee's report and insert the information about what they did with each comment.  So a minor comment (about fixing a typo for example) might be followed by just "Done." A comment about adding some more information might be followed by "Done; see page x, lines y to z."  A comment that one didn't comply with might be followed by a careful explanation of the reasons for not complying.  On the other hand, I've sometimes just written "I've complied with all the referee's comments except x. The reason for the exception is that ...."

Comment: I list the reviewer comment, my reply, and the change.  I repeat this for each comment.  I color code the different parts.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Can you please convert your comment to an answer so that I can vote it up?

Answer (score 1):

At jakebeal's suggestion, I'm converting my comment from Jan. 12 to an answer:

Some people just use the referee's report and insert the information about what they did with each comment. So a minor comment (about fixing a typo for example) might be followed by just "Done." A comment about adding some more information might be followed by "Done; see page x, lines y to z." A comment that one didn't comply with might be followed by a careful explanation of the reasons for not complying. On the other hand, I've sometimes just written "I've complied with all the referee's comments except x. The reason for the exception is that ...."

Comment: I agree with this approach in general. But as a reviewer, I prefer to see a full quote of the changes made to the text in the reviewer document.